# How to display a progress bar during an ajax request (jquery/php)

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, progress-bar

I have an ajax request, whereby I am installing a magento shop automatically, and when the process is done, it would redirect the user to the newly created shop. Here are my codes:

```
   function postSuccessFormData() {
    var targetUrl = '/index.php/install/wizard/successPost';

    jQuery('.form-button').addClass('loading');

   setInterval(installStatus(),4000);
    jQuery.ajax({
        url: targetUrl,
        global: false,
        type: 'POST',
        data: ({
            finish: 1,
            password_key: jQuery('#password_key').val()
        }),
        async: true,
        dataType: 'json',
        error: function() {
            alert("An error has occurred. Please try again.");
        },
        success: function(data) {
            window.location.href = '/';
        }

    });

function installStatus() {
    var installerUpdatesUrl = '/index.php/install/wizard/installerStatus';

    //showProgressBar();
    jQuery.ajax({
        url: installerUpdatesUrl,
       // global: false,
        type: 'GET',
        async: true,
        dataType: 'json',
        error: function (data) {
          //  alert(data.result);
        },
        success: function (data) {

        handle data.result
        var dataKeys = Object.keys(data);
        var lastElementKey = dataKeys[dataKeys.length - 1];
        var lastMessage = data[lastElementKey]['message'];

       if(data[lastElementKey]['progress'] == '') {
            updateProgressBar(data[dataKeys[dataKeys.length - 2]]['progress'],100);
        }

            setting message
            jQuery("#message").html(lastMessage);

            if (data[lastElementKey]['state'] == 'Failure') {
                var stepStr = lastElementKey.split('_');
                var stepString = stepStr[0].toUpperCase() + ' ' + stepStr[1] + ':';

                alert(stepString + "\n" + data[lastElementKey]['message']);
                //hideProgressBar();
                jQuery('.form-button').removeClass('loading');
                return false;
            } else if (data[lastElementKey]['state'] == 'Finish') {
                alert(data[lastElementKey]['message']);
                //hideProgressBar();
                jQuery('.form-button').removeClass('loading');
                //window.location.href = '/';
            } else {
               // installStatus();
            }
        },
        complete: function () {
            installStatus();
            jQuery('.form-button').removeClass('loading');

        }
    });
}
```

The way this is done:

After every 4 seconds the function installStatus is run, which will output the current progress in JSON format. My problem is, this function needs to be executed simultaneously with the function post().

This is not happening, the installStatus is only run after the first function has been completed.

What is wrong?

Answer (score 0):

You are executing `installStatus` when you define it. So this:

```
setInterval(installStatus(),4000);
```

needs to be

```
setInterval(installStatus, 4000);
```

Comment: typo error, thx for pointin out..but it does not really help :(

Answer (score 0):

The new XMLHttpRequest has a nice `progress` event you can listen to show the user the upload progress.

Here's the spec with a nice demo: https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/API/XMLHttpRequest/Using_XMLHttpRequest#Monitoring_progress

Comment: actually, i am not trying to upload anything. I am making an installation, ie creating a full database etc..

Comment: Yeah, well as far as I know you should be able to use the `progress` event during any ajax call.

Comment: if that is the case i won't need a second ajax request , right?

Comment: Oh, I see it now, you need to show the progress of something is happening on the server side. No, in that case my idea don't solve your problem.

Comment: Have you considered using a WebSocket to update in realtime the client about the progress of what's happening in the server ? Anyway It's quite a complex setup to implement the feature ( you'll need a websocket server in primis )

Comment: i am stuck on html 4, websocket doesn't seem appropriate in my ENV..THX

Answer (score 0):

Initially you should call installStatus() only once and then inside the method inside ajax success you should update the procent in the progress bar and call it recursively the same method. On the server side you can save the current procent in a cookie and with every recursive call you can update the cookie and return the procent.

Comment: as far as i know,.it is not possible to create a cookie in the back-end during  an ajax call..the page has to be refreshed..isn't it?

Comment: sorry, i meant cache not cookie. You can save the percent on server side cache object